# Spring batch : JobExecution from PreparedStatementSetter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch with a PreparedStatementSetter for a query reader step. I would like to access to global data from the PreparedStatementSetter that is saved before into the ExecutionContext.

How could I access to the ExecutionContext from this PreparedStatementSetter ?

```
@Component
public class CurrentBatchIdPreparedStatementSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter
{
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException
    {
        // how to access to ExecutionContext here ?
    }
}
```

Thanks

YesWeCan

Answer (score 1):

We can get ExecutionContext from step execution if the scope is step.

```
    @Component
    public class CurrentBatchIdPreparedStatementSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter
    {
       @Value("#{stepExecution}")
       private StepExecution stepExecution;

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException
        {
            final ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
            //Do your operations here
        }
    }
```

You can also get the same from job executioncontext.

```
  @Value("#{jobExecution}")
   private JobExecution jobExecution;
   //inside method
   final ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
```

or you can easily get value from job execution context.

```
        @Value ( "# {jobExecutionContext ['param1']}" ) 
        private String  param1;
        @Value ( "# {jobExecutionContext ['param2']}" )  
        private String  param2;
```